# Does each geo-locations requires a separate authentication using csom?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, multi-geo

Does separate Authentication is required for the each geo-locations(Tenant Instances) ?
If Authentication done then will there be any changes in the CSOM Data ?